Horizontal line in algorithm2e Environment
I am trying to put a line in algorithm2e:
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\IncMargin{1.5em}
\begin{algorithm}  
    algorithm here\;
    \hrule
    algorithm here\;
    \caption{Caption}
\end{algorithm}
\DecMargin{1.5em}
\end{document}


There is a gap at the start and end of the line (indicated by the red arrows). I tried the code from here but it also contains gap. I also tried \moveleft with \vbox which although removes the gap but I have to hardcode the measurements, and it doesn't work with different \IncMargin values in different algorithms.
How to remove this gap? The gap is also affected by \IncMargin, I don't want it to be affected by \IncMargin.

The left margin is \algomargin.
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\newcommand{\algosep}{%
  \par
  \nointerlineskip
  \moveleft\algomargin\vbox{\hrule width \columnwidth}
  \nointerlineskip
}

\begin{document}

\IncMargin{1.5em}
\begin{algorithm}
  algorithm here\;
  \algosep
  algorithm here\;
\caption{Caption}
\end{algorithm}
\DecMargin{1.5em}

\end{document}


The same code but without \IncMargin and \DecMargin will produce

